# I have Crash when Using xml <include/> tag in kotlin

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

i'm coding in ***kotlin*** and using from  in my ***layout.xml*** and when I call a child of ***bottomsheet_map*** layout my app has crash.

my parent layout :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
     ...
    <include layout="@layout/bottomsheet_map" />

    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and bottomsheet_map.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_app"
    android:elevation="@dimen/medium"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/xLarge"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.idmpGroup.rtour.utilities.UI.AnchorSheetBehavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tap_action_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="@dimen/xSmall"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/standard"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/standard"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/medium"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/standard"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/medium">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/xLarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/xSmall"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/dr_btn_radius_solid2" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_title"
                style="@style/tvToolbar_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/show_list"
                android:textColor="#979797" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

when i want set OnClickListener to tap_action_layout in onCreateView i have crash

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false)

        tap_action_layout.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
          //....
        }
        return view
    }
```

**Note:** i would not use findViewByID .is there better solution to call **tap_action_layout** without findViewByID() ????

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.idmpGroup.rtour.fragments.BAS.NearlyFrag.onCreateView(NearlyFrag.kt:258)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: post your error plZ

Comment: can you please add error log?

Comment: if using findViewByID to call child there is no problem... i would not use findViewByID because my child count is very a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this  in `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView`

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        tap_action_layout.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
          //....
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access directly included elements in your code.You need to use **findviewbyid** on parent layout in which you have included other layout.

For Eg:

`<include layout="@layout/bottomsheet_map"
  android:id="@+id/include_layout" />`

```
 val tap_action_layout = include_layout.findViewById(R.id.tap_action_layout)
 tap_action_layout.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
          //....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set **android:id** to `include` tag in xml layout first:

```
<include android:id="@+id/my_layout" 
    layout="@layout/bottomsheet_map" />
```

After you set id you need to call id from include layout tag first to get your **tap_action_layout** not nullable and you should call it from `onViewCreated` method in your fragment: (be aware that this works only if you are using **kotlinx.android.synthetic** for binding views)

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    my_layout.top_action_layout.setOnClickListener {
        // do whatever you wanna do here..
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you are not using kotlin synthetic you would need to call `findViewById(R.id.top_action_layout)` first:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    my_layout.findViewById(R.id.top_action_layout).setOnClickListener {
        // do whatever you wanna do here..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in xml layout  need to set android:id to :

```
<include android:id="@+id/bottomsheet_map_layout" 
    layout="@layout/bottomsheet_map" />
```

then call your views to code in onViewCreated

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    my_layout.top_action_layout.setOnClickListener {
        // do whatever you wanna do here..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `tap_action_layout` needs a view to be executed

Try this

```
val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false)

        view.tap_action_layout.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
          //....
        }
        return view
```

This should work perfectly.